# Set field when Hibernate get object from database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use Hibernate and JPA

I have some POJO

```
public class Pojo {
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date date; 
  @Transient
  private long dLong;
  //other fields
  //getters and setters
}
```

I want to convert `date` to `dLong` when i get object `Pojo` from database.
I can do this when i have object

```
Pojo pojo = repository.findFirst();
Date date = pojo.getDate();
long l = date.getTime();
pojo.setDLong(l);
```

but i want do this when i call `repository.findFirst()`
I tried to use getter and setter  but unsuccessfully.

---

Edit
Top content is example. Sorry but I can't explain my problem with example. Now i show my orignal code:

```
@Entity
public class Medicament {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @Transient
    private long date;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateExpiration;

    //getters and setters
}
```

next i have the service

```
@Service
public class MedicamentService {

    @Autowired
    private MedicamentRepositoryEntityGraph medicamentRepositoryEntityGraph;

    public Medicament findById(int id) {
        return medicamentRepositoryEntityGraph.getOne("select m from Medicament m where m.id="+id, "user", "disease");
    }
}
```

and repository

```
@Repository
public class MedicamentRepositoryEntityGraph {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Medicament getOne(String query, String...param) {
        EntityGraph<Medicament> entityGraph = template(param);
        Medicament medicament = entityManager.createQuery(query, Medicament.class)
            .setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", entityGraph)
            .getSingleResult();
        return medicament;
    }

    private EntityGraph<Medicament> template(String... param) {
        EntityGraph<Medicament> entityGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(Medicament.class);
        entityGraph.addAttributeNodes(param);
        Map<String, Object> hints = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hints.put("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", entityGraph);
        return entityGraph;
    }

}
```

I store in database `dateExpiration` but when I get from database 'Medicament' i want to convert 'dateExpiration' to long 'date' where i use method `findById` from service `MedicamentService`

I tried to use getter and setter but unsuccessfully:

```
public void setDateExpiration(Date dateExpiration) {
        this.dateExpiration = dateExpiration;
        this.date = dateExpiration.getTime();
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just provide a getter that returns `date.getTime()`? What is `repository.findFirst()` - a custom implementation? And is `Pojo` an entity or created via Hibernate's constructor syntax?

Comment: I added some information to main question. That are my first posts on stackoverflow and i have question did you recive message that i edited my   question?

Comment: No, there is no notification if you edit your question.

Comment: Btw, why do you need `date` to return `long` in the first place? And in what way was using a setter unsuccessful?

Comment: @Thomas I use 'long' in my view (spring mvc + jsp) where i convert date from long to MONTH YYYY and in other hand I send object with JSON to android rest client and convert from long to date and store in android sqllite database. I thought I can convert date in getter or setter but i can't (it is not working) - long is still 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate might circumvent the setters but you could make `dLong` a "virtual" property, e.g. like this:

```
public long getDate() {
  if( dateExpiration == null ) { 
    return -1;
  }

  return dateExpiration.getTime();
}

//Be careful with that and add some documentation
public void setDate(long date) {
  dateExpiration = new Date(date);
}
```

Alternatively you could map `date` to the same column as `dateExpiration` and add `insertable = false, updatable = false` to `@Column` but you might have to add a custom user type to convert the DB date to long.

Comment: I can't use "virtual" property becouse I push away the object to view where i use date property as long.

Comment: @TomaszMolenda depending on your framework you could still do that, e.g. if it is based on the Java Beans specification.